# django manage static files accessibility

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

example app tree:

```
articles
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── models.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── article_change.css
│   │   ├── article_create.css
│   │   ├── article_detail.css
│   └── js (obfuscated)
│       ├── article_create.js
│       ├── article_list.js
│       ├── edit_process.js
│       ├── editor.js
│       └── js (readable)
│           ├── article_create.js
│           ├── article_list.js
│           ├── edit_process.js
│           └── editor.js
├── templates
│   └── articles
│       ├── article_create.html
│       ├── article_detail.html
│       ├── edit_process.html
│       └── editor.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

1. `static/js/js` contains javascript that is human readable
2. `static/js` contains obfuscated javascript files.

I wrote a template tag to includes files:

```py
@register.simple_tag
def jstatic(path):
    s = ''
    if settings.DEBUG:
        s = 'js/'
    return static(s + path)
```

in templates, I can do:

```html
<script src="{% jstatic 'js/info.js' %}"></script>
```

which conditionally renders static javascript files based on `DEBUG` mode. whereas, if not in `DEBUG` mode, will serve obfuscated files.

the thing is, I don't want unobfuscated file to be accessed when `DEBUG` is not on, which is running the application on server.

when debug is on, I want user user only to visit obfuscated files:

```
static/js/js/info.js
```

and have no access to

```
static/js/info.js
```

all the apps follows this root tree convention, I wonder if there is a way, for me to block `static/js/info.js` is `DEBUG` is not on.

---

I have thought about shell setting directory permissions, but give up eventually. because, it will not work due to the wrapping structure of the directory. and it will be too much work to modify it, in the project there are about 20 apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible through standard configuration. How to solve this depends on your configuration, but there are three ways to solve this:

- If you use some kind of minifier/webpack like configuration to obfuscate your JS files, you could move the JS files to a src directory and have your tooling *only* copy when DEBUG is True, and copy *and* obfuscate when debug is False.
- You can use two static directories, one for readable files, and the other for obfuscated files (something like src/static/* and dist/static/*), and then only point to the source directory on development environments:
  `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ "src/static", "dist/static"]` vs. `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ "dist/static"]` on production.
  In this case, Django's static files finder will return the first match found.
- Leave your configuration as is, but use a webserver like NGINX for serving static files (Which is already the recommended way to serve static files.) In NGINX's configuration you can define a location that 404's as long as it appears before the location serving your static files.

Comment: thank you, this is detailed answer. just reminds me, I actually run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` on server, I wonder if there is way to overwrite `collectstatic` method so that it ignores unobfuscated file.

Comment: You could also write a custom finder base on one of the staticfiles finders here to override behaviour: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py